# UISplitViewController iOS 5.1 causes popover arrow direction error

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

My app was working perfectly prior to iOS 5.1. It is a `UISplitviewController` with a `UINavigationController` in the left-hand pane, and updates the detail pane dependent upon choices made within that `UINavigationController`.

The new sliding-in from left replacement for the popover, endemic to iOS 5.1 works; it doesn't look great, but it works.

What appears to be broken is the display of the 'popover' from the bar button in portrait. It causes an exception - `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unknown direction passed to _popoverViewSizeForContentSize:arrowDirection:'`

I have tried to override the method which displays the popover as follows:

`-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
{
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.masterPopoverButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}`

But I still get the same error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below delegates to display the master page from details page

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:

    (UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
    {
        barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
        [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
        self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
    }

    - (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
    {
        // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
        [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
        self.masterPopoverController = nil;
    }
```